# Integration testing (preferably TravisCI) in a Gentoo Linux enviornment

Tags: operating-system, continuous-integration, integration-testing, travis-ci, gentoo

I would like to benefit from the excellent package management capabilities and neuro/scientific support of Gentoo Linux when I am setting up continuous integration (CI) testing for my software (e.g. [SAMRI](https://github.com/IBT-FMI/SAMRI)).

Sadly, my favorite platform, TravisCI, seems to offer Ubuntu, Ubuntu, and MacOS environments only. I would like to know how to best (i.e. with minimal overhead and delay) set up a Gentoo Linux environment on TravisCI (or if need be, on another CI platform).

I have tried using the [Gentoo Prefix](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Project:Prefix) bootstrap script, however:

- simply calling it in `- yes "" | ./bootstrap-prefix.ch` will overflow the 4MB log limit
- redirecting it to a file `- yes "" | ./bootstrap-prefix.sh >> prefix_log.txt` will cause the job to time out
- I can't figure out how to increase the time out for such a command. `-
  travis_wait 60 |& yes "" | ./bootstrap-prefix.sh >> prefix_log.txt` times out after 10 minutes.

In excess of all these issues, I feel bootstrapping an entire Gentoo install from scratch is a waste of time and resources. I am thinking maybe this can be more elegantly addressed by using one of the [Gentoo OpenStack](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Project:Openstack) images - or something else?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to test on Gentoo, I suggest using Docker (https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/docker), pull down a small Gentoo image (e.g., https://hub.docker.com/r/gentoo/stage3-amd64/) and run your tests on that image.